# Step up voltage converter in datacenter?

Tags: electrical-power, datacenter, power-supply-unit

I am setting up a rack in the data center that only has 110V. It is redundant, so I thought I could take one from each leg and get 110V, but when I used a voltmeter last night they somehow are on the same frequency so I don't get 220V out of it. I was looking at a 110V-220V converter (https://smile.amazon.com/LiteFuze-Voltage-Converter-Transformer-Regulator/dp/B07D7JPJDP), but wasn't sure if this is a horrible idea?

It is to power a 84 HDD JBOD array (Xyratex OneStor 2584). I realize I can get dedicated 220V power, but it adds a couple hundred a month and this is the only device that requires it.

Doing the math of 25W per drive during spin up gives just over 2000W at peak draw (not counting cooling fans and such, so a 5000W technically seems sufficient, but wondering if anyone else has done this?

Comment: It's almost a certainty that the data center is not going to allow you to do this.

Comment: Why would they know? As long as I am not over my amp limit on 110 it doesn't seem like it would matter

Comment: 1. They most assuredly inspect the data center racks on a regular basis and will see it. 2. They surely monitor what equipment customers bring into the data center. 3. They'll likely detect it in their power system monitoring. 4. They most likely prohibit this in your contract and you'll probably open yourself up to some type of penalties or risk getting yourself (and your equipment) kicked out of the data center. 5. It isn't about going over your limits, it's about ensuring the safety of the data center personnel, customers, and equipment.

Comment: I called the datacenter and the first guy I talked to didn't see a problem with it but he is going to check with the DC manager. My primary concern other than that would be about "dirty power" and damaging the unit. I wasn't sure how reliable this idea would be.

Comment: Buy from a reputable source. Not some random off Amazon. First rule: no datasheet no sale. And please provide a datasheet or some such for your server if you expect anyone to look seriously at this. And please, pick something designed for a rack space. The device you linked uses side vents for cooling. Sounds like that might not work...

Comment: I understand that you don't want to pay that extra DC bill. But pick a good device. Right now it looks like you want to risk your expensive storage server and open up a liability to lawsuits from the DC should something go wrong to save a few hundred bucks. And CE is worthless unless they sell in Europe too.

Comment: I was wandering around my office and found a couple 220V rackmount APC UPS systems from an office I sold last year. I should be able to feed power in using the converter and then get good clean power out. It takes up an extra 4U, but I have plenty of extra space at the moment. Waiting to hear back from the DC.